# How to Programmatically add a ToolstripDropDownButton to a toolstrip with dropdown menu (C# Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a toolstrip that will contain toolstripdropdownbuttons that represent folders that are found in a directory.  I would like a dropdown menu to each toolstripdropdownbutton to contain subfolders that are found.  An example of this would be the Internet Explorer Links bar I have tried the following code but I'm not quite sure how to go about it (see picture)
[Links Bar Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl0Rq.jpg)

Code I have tried:

```
        private void populateLinks()
    {
        linksToolStrip.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo linksFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites) + "\\Links");
        foreach (DirectoryInfo linksDirectory in linksFolder.GetDirectories())
        {
            Image favImage = Properties.Resources.Folder;
            ToolStripDropDownButton button = new ToolStripDropDownButton();
            button.Text = Truncate(linksDirectory.Name, 22);
            button.ToolTipText = linksDirectory.Name + "\nDate Created: " + Directory.GetCreationTime(linksDirectory.FullName);
            button.Image = favImage;
            button.Tag = linksDirectory.FullName;
            linksToolStrip.Items.Add(button);
            populateLinksFolders(linksDirectory, button.DropDown);

        }
```

and

```
private void populateLinksFolders(DirectoryInfo subdirectory, ToolStripDropDown tsdd)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in subdirectory.GetDirectories())
        {
            populateLinksFolders(directory, ?) //<- Everything tried here fails
        }
    }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `ToolStripDropDownButton`, then use the `DropDownItems` property to add subitems.

```
populateLinksFolders(linksDirectory, button);
```

Then:

```
private void populateLinksFolders(DirectoryInfo subdirectory, ToolStripDropDownButton tsddb)
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in subdirectory.GetDirectories())
    {
        ToolStripDropDownButton button = new ToolStripDropDownButton(directory.Name);
        tsddb.DropDownItems.Add(button);
        populateLinksFolders(directory, button);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this answered my queston

Comment: An interesting problem came about where the drop down menu is too small, is there a way to auto size it or fix this?

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider using the check mark next to the answer. The button should auto size by default, but if it doesn't you can add `button.AutoSize = true;`.

Comment: I tired that but it did not work I tried setting it for both the button and for the drop down menu.  I have attached a picture as to what it is doing.  
![Links Result](http://imgur.com/erNBcmN).